# TargetInvocationException when launching ASP page with objectDataSource fed Gridview

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I'm receiving the below exception when I launch the page for debugging. The objectDataSource is configured for an ADO TableAdapter which queries an oracle database. The ods is then bound to an ASP.NET Gridview. I am coding against .NET 4.0.

If I leave the gridview unbound, there are no problems when launching. I can do as much as completely configure the ods, define columns and row behavior for the gridview, etc, and there are no issues. I am using (to my knowledge) the same methodology that I have successfully used  many times in the past to access and display the data. I've been through the code as closely as I can imagine, and haven't been able to pick out the problem.

Exception Info:

```
Capabilities:Type=IE7,Name=IE,Version=7.0,MajorVersion=7,MinorVersion=0,Platform=WinNT,IsBeta=False,IsCrawler=False,IsAOL=False,IsWin16=False,IsWin32=True,SupportsFrames=True,SupportsTables=True,SupportsCookies=True,Ecmascriptversion=3.0,SupportsVBScript=True,SupportsJavaApplets=True,SupportsActiveXControls=True,CDF= False 

Inner Exception Type: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Inner Exception: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
Inner Source: mscorlib 
Inner Stack Trace: at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) 
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.InvokeMethod(ObjectDataSourceMethod method, Boolean disposeInstance, Object& instance) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) 
at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() 
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
```

The Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvGradename" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataKeyNames="GRADENAME_ID" DataSourceID="odsGradename">
                    <Columns>

                        //Which columns are displayed are irrelevant. The error occurs with any columns, including none.

                    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsGradename" runat="server" 
                    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
                    SelectMethod="GetDataByActiveName" 
                    TypeName="pts.PTSTableAdapters.PTS_GRADENAMETableAdapter">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The query:

```
select gn.gradename_id 
      , gn.mill_id
      , case when gn.gradename_id = 0 then upper(gn.name) else initcap(gn.name) end name
      , m.name millname
      , gn.audit_id
      , gn.audit_dtm
      , gn.audit_insert_dtm
      , gn.audit_process_code
      , gn.description
      , gn.roll_width_threshold
from pts_gradename gn
  , pts_mill m
where gn.is_generic = 1 
  and gn.is_active = 1
  and gn.mill_id = m.mill_id
order by case when gn.gradename_id = 0 then null else initcap(gn.name) end nulls first
```

I'm not doing anything with it in the code-behind, at the moment.

EDIT: included tablenames in the query, where they had been redacted, previously.

Also, I can preview the data in the table adapter, and receive the expected information, so it appears not to be a problem with the query itself.

Comment: Most probably, your `GetDataByActiveName` just throws an exception. Debug it carefully.

Comment: I'll take a closer look there. I've noted in the main question that I can "preview data" on the query without issue. The method itself is auto-generated by the framework.

Comment: This appears to be it, or at least the right direction - the generated Fill method that backs the GetDataByActiveName fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the auto-generated Fill method associated with the datatable. I wasn't able to determine what exactly the problem was, but deleting it and starting over fixed the problem.

Not really a great answer, but it was the solution to this particular issue.